# Filtering based on nested struct/array

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is the schema:

```
root
 |-- target_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- sub_column: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- sub_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- title: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- scopes: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Add a column that returns the `title` IF `scopes` contains the string "dog", if it doesn't return ""

Here is an example:

target_column

```
[{a,[{a1, title1, []}}, {b,[{b1, title2, [cat, dog]}]}]
[{a,[{a1, title1, []}}, {c,[{c1, title3, [cat, rabbit]}]}, {d,[{d1, title4, [cat]}, {d2, title5, [kitten]}]}]
```

This would return

```
final_columns
title2
[]
```

I'm new to scala so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code snippet to achieve the desired output:

```
val sac = new SparkContext("local[*]", " first Program");
val sqlc = new SQLContext(sac);
import sqlc.implicits._;
 val jsondata=
      """
        |{
        |   "target_column": [{
                    |   "id" : "a",
                    |   "sub_column" : [{
                    |   "sub_id" : "a1", 
                    |   "title" : "title1", 
                    |   "scopes": []
                |   }]
            |   },
                |   {
                    |   "id" : "b",
                    |   "sub_column" : [{
                    |   "sub_id" : "b1", 
                    |   "title" : "title2", 
                    |   "scopes": ["cat", "dog"]
                |   }]
            |   }
        |   ]
        |}
      """.stripMargin 
      
    val df = sqlc.read.json(Seq(jsondata).toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()
    df.createOrReplaceTempView("targetInfo")
    val df2 = sqlc.sql("select explode(target_column.sub_column) from targetInfo")
    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()
    df2.createOrReplaceTempView("scopesInfo")
    sqlc.sql("select col.title from scopesInfo where array_contains(flatten(col.scopes), 'dog')").show(false)
    sqlc.sql("SELECT *, CASE WHEN array_contains(flatten(col.scopes), 'dog') THEN concat_ws(',',col.title) ELSE '' END AS final_columns FROM scopesInfo").show(false)
```

This results following OUTPUT :

```
+--------------------------+-------------+
|col                       |final_columns|
+--------------------------+-------------+
|[[[], a1, title1]]        |             |
|[[[cat, dog], b1, title2]]|title2       |
+--------------------------+-------------+
```

Hope I got your question right.

Answer (score 0):

Here is slightly different approach, although Rakhi's might be the one you want.

This will give you one record per array element in `target_column`. This makes more sense to me, but if you need just one record per original record, you can perform a `flatten(collect_list($"titles"))` afterwards (shown below).

First, the data (edited to show effect of flattening):

```
{"target_column": [{"id": "a","sub_column": [{"sub_id": "a1", "title": "title1", "scopes": ["dog"]}]}, {"id": "b", "sub_column": [{"sub_id": "b1", "title": "title2", "scopes": ["cat", "dog"]}]}]}
{"target_column": [{"id": "a","sub_column": [{"sub_id": "a1", "title": "title1", "scopes": []}]}, {"id": "c","sub_column": [{"sub_id": "c1", "title": "title3", "scopes": ["cat", "rabbit"]}]}, {"id": "d","sub_column": [{"sub_id": "d1", "title": "title4", "scopes": ["cat"]}, {"sub_id": "d2", "title": "title5", "scopes": ["kitten"]}]}]}
```

Now load the data and add some array operations (note that these are just lazy operations, until `show` is invoked):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

// "spark" is your SparkSession
// Note all variables with "df" in them are of DataFrame type
// and titleCond is an org.apache.spark.sql.Column
val df = spark.read.json("example.json")
val dfSub = df.withColumn("sub_column", explode($"target_column.sub_column"))
val titleCond = expr("array_contains(flatten(sub_column.scopes), 'dog')")
val dfResult = dfSub.withColumn("titles", when(titleCond, $"sub_column.title").otherwise(array().cast("array<string>")))

dfResult.drop($"target_column").show(false)
```

Result (ungrouped):

```
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|sub_column                                   |titles  |
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
|[[[dog], a1, title1]]                        |[title1]|
|[[[cat, dog], b1, title2]]                   |[title2]|
|[[[], a1, title1]]                           |[]      |
|[[[cat, rabbit], c1, title3]]                |[]      |
|[[[cat], d1, title4], [[kitten], d2, title5]]|[]      |
+---------------------------------------------+--------+
```

If you prefer grouping by original source records:

```
val dfGrouped = dfResult.groupBy($"target_column").agg(flatten(collect_list($"titles")).alias("titles"))
```

Result (grouped):

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|target_column                                                                                                    |titles          |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
|[[a, [[[dog], a1, title1]]], [b, [[[cat, dog], b1, title2]]]]                                                    |[title1, title2]|
|[[a, [[[], a1, title1]]], [c, [[[cat, rabbit], c1, title3]]], [d, [[[cat], d1, title4], [[kitten], d2, title5]]]]|[]              |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+
```